# scheduling crawler by airflow

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, airflow, web-crawler

```
import datetime as dt
from pendulum import timezone

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

import asyncio
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import requests

import re

from discord import Webhook, Embed, Color
import aiohttp


def crawl_data(**context):

    import logging

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    load_dotenv()

    login_url = os.environ.get('login_url')
    login_data = {
        'Id': os.environ.get('username'),
        'password': os.environ.get('pwd')
    }

    user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
    chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    service = ChromeService(executable_path='{chrome driver path}')
    chrome_option.add_argument('headless')
    chrome_option.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent["User-Agent"]}')
    chrome_option.add_argument('disable-gpu')
    chrome_option.add_argument('lang=ko_KR')
    chrome_option.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_option.add_argument("start-maximized")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_option)
    browser.get(login_url)

    time.sleep(3)
    elem_id = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'loginUserId')
    elem_id.send_keys(login_data['Id'])
    time.sleep(1)

    elem_pw = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'loginPassword')
    elem_pw.send_keys(login_data['password'])
    time.sleep(1)

    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'kt_login_signin_submit').click()
    time.sleep(3)

    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 40)
    wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'kt-widget16__items'), '$'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    logging.info("------------------------------------------------")
    browser.quit()
    logging.info(f'{"-" * 100}\ncontext : {soup}')
    source_cost_data = list()
    
    # data processing logic

    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='cost_data', value=source_cost_data)
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='data_period', value=period)
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='exchange_rate', value=exchange_rate)


def create_embed(**context):

    import logging

    logging.info(f"{'-'*100}\ncreate embed")

    source_cost_data = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key='cost_data')
    period = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key='data_period')
    exchange_rate = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key='exchange_rate')

    total_cost = sum([float(i[1][1:]) for i in source_cost_data])

    # create embed

    asyncio.run(send_fee_data(Content))

async def send_fee_data(content):

    import logging

    discord_url = os.environ.get('discord_webhook_url')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url(discord_url, session=session)
        await webhook.send(embed=content, username='aws 비용 봇')

    logging.info('success!')


with DAG(
    'crawl_test',
    description='test desc',
    start_date=dt.datetime(2023,10,15, tzinfo=timezone("Asia/Seoul")),
    schedule_interval='23 11 * * *',
    tags=['cron', 'crawl']
) as dag:

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="crawling",
        python_callable=crawl_data,
        retries=1,
        retry_delay=dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
    )

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="creating_embed",
        python_callable=create_embed,
        retries=1,
        retry_delay=dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
    )

    t1 >> t2
```

the code above work well with statement `dag.test()` and command `airflow dags test crawl_test 20231015`

but if I initiate airflow server using `airflow standalone` or `airflow webserver` with `airflow scheduler` and the dag is executed as scheduled by cron, it get in stuck at `browser.quit()`

the logging above `browser.quit()` works but the below does not
[image: log]

I've been spent three days at this.
Why on earth does it work when testing, but not by scheduler

It originally got in stuck `service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())`.
So I download webdriver manually and using local path.
And it was solved.
But now `brower.quit()` is a problem

[image]
the entire log
It says OOM but idle memory on my mac is 26%(total 32g)

I retried without headless option, and checked that the browser window turns off but does not run the following code